# Printing multiple copies of movieclip as3

Tags: actionscript-3, printing

I have an app that prints stickers. Using numerical stepper I can choose how many sticker must be printed. There can be 3 per page max. How can I make copies of movieclip with sticker in it? How can I make them have serial numbers (for example 1 of 5, 2 of 5, 3 of 5, 4 of 5, 5 of 5)? I now have a pre made movieclip with 3 stickers and when I choose 5 stickers it prints 2 pages (6 stickers, if I print 8 it prints 3 pages etc.)

```
function STRPRNButtonStatus(event:MouseEvent) {
var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
var pagesToPrint:uint = 0;
var ALL_STR_NUM_print = (ALL_STR_NUM.value/3);
var num1:Number = UNT_NUM.value;
var res1:Number = Math.ceil(num1/3);
 var UNT_NUM_print = res1;
 if (DLV_NUM_CHK.selected) {
 printJob.copies = UNT_NUM_print;
 }
 else printJob.copies = ALL_STR_NUM_print;

 var started:Boolean = printJob.start2(null, false);
if (started) {
}
try {
  if (STR_CHK1.selected) {
 printJob.addPage(Sticker1);
 pagesToPrint++;
 }
}
catch (error:Error) 
            { 
}
 if(pagesToPrint > 0) {
printJob.send();
     }
        else 
        { 
           printJob.terminate(); 
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can change visiblity of not required sticker from the page and then have some dynamic assets in sticker and change them as per your requirements.

Comment: I have a movieclip Sticker1 with 3 stickers in it. When I need 5 I print 2 copies of Sticker1. How can I make 1 sticker in second copie invisible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together a small explanation of how you should do that

```
function STRPRNButtonStatus( event:MouseEvent ) 
{
    /*change it as per your requirements*/
    var stickerToPrint:uint = 8;
    var stickerPerPage:uint = 3;
    var stickerOnPage:uint = 3;
    var pageNum:uint = 0;
    /*begin a print job*/
    var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
    /*test if start*/
    if ( printJob.start() ) 
    {
        /*get how many page required*/
        var totalPageRequired:uint = Math.ceil( stickerToPrint/stickerPerPage);
        for( var i:uint =0; i<totalPageRequired;i++)
        {
            /*calculate how many sticker already printed*/
            stickerOnPage = stickerToPrint - (pageNum*3);
            /*now check how many need on this page*/
            if( stickerOnPage>3)stickerOnPage = 3;

            for( var j:uint =stickerOnPage+1; j<=3;j++)
            {
                //here you hide the sticker, I simply assume that yourmain sticker contain sticker_1, sticker_2 and sticker_3 movieclips
                sticker["sticker_"+j].visible = false;
            }   
            printJob.addPage(sticker);
            ++pageNum;
        }

        /* Send print job to printer */
        if( totalPageRequired > 0 )printJob.send();

        /* Delete job from memory */
        printJob = null;

    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But there is one problem. It doesn't print at all if I select only one sticker and prints one less sticker if I select 4,7,10,13 etc.

Comment: Changed      var totalPageRequired:uint = Math.round( stickerToPrint/stickerPerPage);      to        var totalPageRequired:uint = Math.ceil( stickerToPrint/stickerPerPage);       now it's ok.

Comment: Any idea how to make them have serial numbers (for example 1 of 5, 2 of 5, 3 of 5, 4 of 5, 5 of 5)?

Comment: Ah you are right, I used round, which is wrong, ceil is correct way to do that.

Comment: Have a dynamic textfield in the sticker and update it in the loop.